# How to get diff of PR in a GitHub workflow step?

Tags: git, github, workflow, diff, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow that is supposed to send a single diff to a different service.

The diff shall be that of the PR for which the workflow is running.

I know that there's the `actions/checkout@v2` action but

```yaml
       # Checkout pull request HEAD commit instead of merge commit
       # https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-pull-request-head-commit-instead-of-merge-commit
       - name: Checkout pull request HEAD
         id: checkout_pr_head
         uses: actions/checkout@v2
         with:
           ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
           fetch-depth: 0
```

Now, in the next step of the workflow I tried to print the diff but it doesn't work as in: the diff is empty:

```yaml
      - name: print-diff
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git diff origin/main..HEAD > mydiff
          echo "mydiff = "
          cat mydiff
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch the branch you are diffing against, because the `checkout` action doesn't fetch all branches:

```
      - name: print-diff
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git fetch origin main
          git diff origin/main..HEAD > mydiff
          echo "mydiff = "
          cat mydiff
```